# Android multiplayer game SDK development

Tags: android, android-studio, multiplayer, android-multiple-users

I am developing an Android App in Android Studio. The application is essentially a 1 vs 1 game where gameplay is as follows:

- A 10 second joint planning phase where the players both plan their moves against each other on their own devices
- followed by a 10 second 'play' phase where the moves they both planned just then are played out on both devices

This is played until one of the players is deemed victorious.

My question is essentially, by my understanding this does not fit the Android [Real-Time](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer) or [Turn-Based](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer) game parts of the SDK which have been well documented and developed.

I see three solutions:

1. Change the underlying premise of the game to fit into the Real-Time/Turn-Based game spec
2. Keep the premise of the game and alter the Real-Time/Turn-Based game spec to suit my needs
3. Develop my own logic etc and build a framework

Option 3 is obviously the hardest, and then I am unsure which is easier, options 1 or 2?

Thanks in advance for the help if you read this far!!